# Can't paginate a custom post type query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Trying to show custom post type offers one by one, paginating them in a custom page template by 1. But it's still showing all the posts. 
Here is the code

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : '1';
$args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'offers',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_per_page' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'offer_order',
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'tax_query'     => array(
              array(
                'taxonomy' => 'campaigns',  
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 
                  'test-campaign'
                )
              )
            )
  );

$new = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) while ($new->have_posts()) : $new->the_post(); ?>
<div>Post Layout</div>
<?php 
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `post_per_page` with `posts_per_pages` in your Array args

——

After endwhile and before of wp_reset_postdata insert this code

```
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $new->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: Replace key ‘post_per_page’ with ‘posts_per_page’ (add “s”)

Comment: F\## me... Thanks!

Comment: No Problem! :-)